# What is "check_scoring" in sklearn.metrics?

Tags: scikit-learn, metrics, make-scorer

What is `check_scoring` in `sklearn.metrics`, how does it work, and what is it its difference with `make_scorer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`check_scoring`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.check_scoring.html) is mainly used as an internal method to ensure score methods are valid.

It returns the same type of instance as a `make_scorer`, or a default score if `None` is provided:

```py
>>> from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
>>> from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
>>> clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
>>> regr = DecisionTreeRegressor()

>>> from sklearn.metrics import check_scoring

>>> check_scoring(clf, scoring="recall")
make_scorer(recall_score, average=binary)

>>> check_scoring(regr, scoring="r2")
make_scorer(r2_score)
```

So: you'll probably use [`make_scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) more often.

**See also**: [`scoring` in scikit-learn's glossary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-scoring)